# Jquery Dialog with disappearing inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following:

```
$(function(){
      // initialize dialogs for every row

$( ".new_dag").each(function(index){
    var this_id = index+1;
    $(this).attr("id", 'add_table_'+this_id);           
    $(this).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
            height: 200,
            width: 260,
            resizable: true,
            draggable: true,
            modal: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "puff",
            title: "Additional Information on line "+this_id
    }); 
});


$('a#open_add').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
    $("div#add_table_"+id).dialog("open");
});

});


<form id="new" method="POST">
   <div class="new_dag" id="add_table_<?php echo $g; ?>">
      <table width="100%" border="1"  >
        <tr>
          <td height="22" colspan="2" align="center"><strong>Additional Information</strong></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>E.D.L:</td>
          <td><input name="edl[]" size="15"  type="text"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>E.O:</td>
          <td><input name="eo[]" size="15" type="text"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>R.F.C:</td>
          <td><input name="rfc[]" size="15" type="text"  /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </div> 
</form>
```

What happens here is that when the link is clicked a dialog appears with the information contained in the div with class 'new_dag'. However, once that dialog appears and fill out the information contained in the inputs, they never POST. It's as though those inputs were somehow removed from the form... if that's possible..

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a dialog, it gets automatically appended to the end of the `body`.
You can specify where to put it by using the [`appendTo`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo) parameter.

Comment: strange... can you use an inspector to check where the dialog div is placed?